# How to route regular domain entry to secure port 443 using Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have PHP website (will call it awesomedomain.com from now on.) currently load balanced in Elastic Beanstalk with SSL up and running.

I can obtain a secure connection to the site with https://awesomedomain.com/ however whenever I enter "awesomedomain.com" it still connects as unsecure port.

I have two listeners 80 and 443 set-up. How can I route all coming traffic to port 443 for global SSL connection?

Thanks to anyone beforehand.

Cheers,

~bio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set two ways :

1. Setup rule is host file :

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName abc.example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://abc.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName abc.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
  SSLEngine On 
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to restart server after this changes.

2. In `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 

RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

3. If you are using CloudFront and ELB as endpoint for ssl certificate then CloudFront has option to redirect http to https all request.

Comment: This may break a load balancer's health check without further configuration to prevent redirects at the health check URL. It also won't work behind a load balancer that is terminating SSL, since the server will always see the request as HTTP, and will need to check a header for the original protocol.

Comment: You are right. There are different to achieved out of best have to select.

Answer (score 1):

When you just type "awesomedomain.com" the browser automatically adds "http://" to that, and then tries to hit port `80` of that server. Your application has to send a redirect on requests from port 80 to port 443 to force the browser to use SSL. If you are using an application load balancer (ALB), or CloudFront, you can configure the redirect there. Otherwise your server needs to detect the value of the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header from the load balancer, and issue a redirect if that is not `443`.

The method of doing this in Elastic Beanstalk is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html).